# How to unit test U-SQL scripts?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I currently have a U-SQL project with a set of different scripts, and i am trying to create unit tests for them. I can run the scripts locally using the Azure Data Lake tools with a set of test data and generate the expected outputs.
The scripts are pure U-SQL data manipulation/transformation so because there are no methods i am not sure whats the correct approach to test this? 
If anyone has any experience/idea on how it should be done or any documentation please feel free to help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake provides U-SQL SDK that helps you run U-SQL script locally through command line and programming interface, it performs same local run action in ADL VS Tool. Here is the reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk