# Unit Testing U-sql Scripts

Tags: unit-testing, u-sql

I want to unit test the u-sql scripts which does not contain any user defined object and user defined functions.
Please let me know how to unit test the u-sql scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test U-SQL scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664423/how-to-unit-test-u-sql-scripts)

Comment: Agreed duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664423/how-to-unit-test-u-sql-scripts

Comment: In that link the details are about unit testing on local and not on portal so I want how to do unit testing on azure portal.

Comment: Do you mean the portal directly as in the UI? Or do you mean submitting the scripts during unit testing against the cluster?

Comment: submitting the scripts during unit testing against the cluster